# How to edit the slug/permalink in Gutenberg?

Tags: permalinks, slug, block-editor

After updating to WordPress 5 and creating a new post, I can add a title, but how do I edit the slug or permalink?

Answer (score 4):

To view and edit the slug, you need to be in the Code Editor view.

- Click on the Show more tools button on the upper right corner of the toolbar and click on Code Editor

[image]

- Click on the title and the slug/permalink will appear above.

[image]

In either Visual or Code Editor, clicking on the title also shows the permalink on the sidebar.

[image]

Comment: The permalink box may not appear until the post has been published.

Comment: Also, if you're working on a brand new site, you'll need to make sure a slug-based Permalink Structure is saved, otherwise, Gutenberg may hide slug related fields.

Comment: For custom post types, slug can only be edited if `public` is set to `true` and `rewrite` enabled in the registering arguments

Comment: Does this actually work on new posts before publishing them? I'm not seeing how to change the permalink or slug prior to publishing.